# Model binding dynamic Radio Button value using Viewbag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using razor to generate radio buttons. However when I submit, the value being passed is

> System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

Instead of an actual string value like `"1234"` (which is what I am expecting)

This is my html code

```
@foreach (var lists in ViewBag.Lists)
{
    <span class="nowrap">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Lists, (SelectList)ViewBag.Lists, new { id = "list" + lists.Value)

        <label for="list@(lists.Value)" style="color:#808080;font-weight:100">@lists.Text</label>
    </span>
}
```

I've tried replacing `(SelectList)ViewBag.Lists` with `lists.Value` but it'll bark with

> Error CS1929  'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'RadioButtonFor' and the best extension method overload
>   'InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor(HtmlHelper,
>   Expression>, object, object)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'HtmlHelper'

Here's the repository method

```
public SelectList GetListsByLocation(int locationId)
{
    using (var ctx = new V4Entities())
    {
        var query = (from l in ctx.FooBarConfig
        where l.IsActive
        where l.LocationId == locationId
        orderby l.ServiceTypeId, l.Name
        select l);
        return new SelectList(query.ToList(), "UplistConfigId", "Name");
    }
}
```

Which is being assigned in a controller method for the page.

```
ViewBag.Lists = _upListConfigRepo.GetListsByLocation(TnuSession.Current.LocationId);
```

My question is, what argument should I pass for the second parameter of Html.RadioButtonFor so that when I submit, I receive the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following chandrakant's answer, it led me on the right path. His answer, however, threw me an error:

> 'Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<\TheNextUp.Model.UpListConfig>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<\System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>''

Had to cast mine as such

```
@foreach (var lists in (SelectList)ViewBag.lists)
{
    <span class="nowrap">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Lists, lists.Value, new { id = "list" + lists.Value, name = "Lists", @value = lists.Value, @text = lists.Text })
        <label for="list@(lists.Value)" style="color:#808080;font-weight:100">@lists.Text</label>
    </span>
}
```

Then, the second parameter for `RadioButtonFor` needed to be `lists.Value` in order to pass the value of that radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ViewBag.List variable directly in Radiobuttonfor(), which is wrong

Below code should work for you

```
@foreach (var lists in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lists.Items)
{
    <span class="nowrap">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Lists, lists, new { id = "list" + lists.Value })

        <label for="list@(lists.Value)" style="color:#808080;font-weight:100">@lists.Text</label>
    </span>
}
```

Comment: You were close, sir! You definitely led me on the right track by casting the ViewBag in the foreach loop. I had to cast mine (SelectList)ViewBag.lists. Thank you for your time and help!